# How user <h:messages> only if not null messages?

Tags: html, css, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I was thinking in use `<h:messages>` in a better way, something like this:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessages}">
  <hr/>
  <h3>Please inform us about:</h3>
  <h:messages globalOnly="true"  escape="false" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

The idea is show the message to the user in a different way, with more style.
Is that possible ?

Comment: Isn't applying some [CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/) rules enough for your situation?

Comment: no, because `<hr/> for example, as `<h3>Please inform us about:</h3>` would only shown if the condition was `true`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're available by [`FacesContext#getMessageList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getMessageList%28%29) in JSF API and thus by `#{facesContext.messageList}` in EL.

If you'd like to check if there are any messages:

```
<h:panelGroup ... rendered="#{not empty facesContext.messageList}">
```

Or if you'd like to check if there are any global messages:

```
<h:panelGroup ... rendered="#{not empty facesContext.getMessageList(null)}">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try jNotify. Here is some code from my application. It requires the page to reload to show the messages. Each message should appear separately. It uses jNotify 2.1 plugin and jQuery 1.5.1. I hope this helps

[link to jNotify example usage](http://demos.myjqueryplugins.com/jnotify/)

```
<h:messages styleClass="zewError" 
                showDetail="false" 
                globalOnly="false" 
                infoClass="infoMes" 
                errorClass="errorMes" />
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{
    $('.infoMes').each(

    function(){

  jSuccess(''+$(this).html()), //add <h3>Please inform us about:</h3> here
    {
      autoHide : false, // added in v2.0
      clickOverlay : true, // added in v2.0
      MinWidth : 250,
      TimeShown : 3000,
      ShowTimeEffect : 200,
      HideTimeEffect : 200,
      LongTrip :20,
      HorizontalPosition : 'left',
      VerticalPosition : 'bottom',
      ShowOverlay : true,
      ColorOverlay : '#000',
      OpacityOverlay : 0.3,
      onClosed : function(){ // added in v2.0

      },
      onCompleted : function(){ // added in v2.0

      }
    }
  });

      $('.errorMes').each(

    function(){

  jError(''+$(this).html()),
    {
      autoHide : false, // added in v2.0
      clickOverlay : true, // added in v2.0
      MinWidth : 250,
      TimeShown : 3000,
      ShowTimeEffect : 200,
      HideTimeEffect : 200,
      LongTrip :20,
      HorizontalPosition : 'left',
      VerticalPosition : 'bottom',
      ShowOverlay : true,
      ColorOverlay : '#000',
      OpacityOverlay : 0.3,
      onClosed : function(){ // added in v2.0

      },
      onCompleted : function(){ // added in v2.0

      }
    }
  });

      $('.zewError').remove();
}
);
```